# How to generate C# class files (.cs) from .proto files

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

Can anyone help me step by step method to generate c# class files from .proto files. I have been following the link http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/ but it is not that clear to me.

Comment: The wiki contains a step-by-step page: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/wiki/GettingStarted - please say what goes wrong when you try that.

Comment: protobuf-csharp-port is not the same as protobuf-net; re-tagging

Comment: What brought me here was trying to follow instructions in the .chm file.  Very confusing compared to the Wiki page.

Comment: You can download proto compiler from [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0-beta-2/protoc-3.0.0-beta-2-win32.zip). When you have protoc installed you need to call `protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --csharp_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/your.proto`. Beware that "C# code generator only supports generating **proto3**". It will support proto2 [soon](https://github.com/ctaggart/froto/pull/13) [AFIK](https://github.com/ctaggart/froto/issues/6)

Comment: [Version 3.0.0-alpha-3](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0-alpha-3/protoc-3.0.0-alpha-3-win32.zip) generates C# from both proto2 and proto3.

Comment: @SashaZezulinsky Where do you see that it supports proto2? All the documentation I see specifically excludes proto2. To quote the (Alpha) section: "proto2 files are prohibited for C# codegen"

Comment: @Jake1164 I wrote that _it will support soon_ here is [pull request](https://github.com/ctaggart/froto/pull/13)

Comment: Fair enough, I didnt see the previous post until I expanded the list.